Sending an OPTIONS request using PJSUA2
I'm working on an Android PJSIP app, and I was told I will need to periodically send the server requests using the OPTIONS method. I was not able to find any reference to doing this using the PJSUA2 API.
I managed to send an OPTIONS request inside a call context using Call.SendRequest(requestParam), but I need to be able to do this outside of a call to receive a keep-alive back from the server.
Any help will be appreciated!

please provide full code

@MuhammadShah This is not an error with my code, I am just trying to find a code example of how to send an OPTIONS request.
